# Select top 1 Student Fee From List In SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my SQL Server table, I have this data:

```
+------+-----+------------+
| Name | Fee | Date_Time  |
+------+-----+------------+
| AA   | 50  | 2018-03-27 |
| AA   | 30  | 2018-04-10 |
| BB   | 40  | 2018-01-10 |
| BB   | 10  | 2018-04-10 |
| CC   | 10  | 2018-04-10 |
| DD   | 10  | 2018-04-10 |
+------+-----+------------+
```

How can I get data using SQL query like `TOP 1` for (AA, BB, CC, DD) `ORDER BY Date_Time DESC` into a list?

```
+------+-----+------------+
| Name | Fee | Date_Time  |
+------+-----+------------+
| AA   | 30  | 2018-04-10 |
| BB   | 10  | 2018-04-10 |
| CC   | 10  | 2018-04-10 |
| DD   | 10  | 2018-04-10 |
+------+-----+------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `row_number()` function to get the top most `Fee`

```
select top(1) with ties Name, Fee, Date_Time  
from table t
order by row_number() over (partition by Name order by Date_Time desc)
```

Comment: Is there some reason why I'm seeing more people use this syntax recently (even though it's a bit less efficient than the regular way of doing it (e.g. PSK's answer) because it does two sorts instead of one)?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach can be

```
SELECT Name,Fee,Date_Time FROM
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY DATE_TIME DESC) RN
  FROM [TABLE_NAME]
 ) T
 WHERE RN=1
```

In case if you have multiple entries on same day for a particular fee, and you want both should appear you can use `DENSE_RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()` like following.

```
SELECT Name,Fee,Date_Time FROM
(
  SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY DATE_TIME DESC) RN
  FROM [TABLE_NAME]
 ) T
 WHERE RN=1
```

**<kbd>[DEMO](http://rextester.com/HTELHP68888)</kbd>**

Answer (score 0):

Give a `row_number` based on the partition by `Name` and order by descending order of `Date_Time` and then select rows having row_number is 1.

**Query**

```
;with cte as (
    select [rn] = row_number() over(
        partition by [Name]
        order by [Date_Time] desc
    ), *
    from [your_table_name]
)
select [Name], [Fee], [Date_Time]
from cte
where [rn] = 1;
```